# css z-index/div display

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have a drop down sign in menu which works fine in webkit/firefox, but doesn't display in Internet Explorer. However, I have the exact same sign in menu on a different site which does display in IE!
Have a look here for the non working version:
https://www.graduationregistration.com/new
and here for a working version:
http://www.inthestar.com

I've tried all values of z-indexes and styling but just can't get it to work and I really need it to!! Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance!!

The CSS is below (it's the same for both sites):

```
#signin_menu {
-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
display:none;
background-color:#ddeef6;
position:absolute;
right: -2px;
width:210px;
z-index:10;
border:1px transparent;
text-align:right;
padding:12px;
top: 24.5px; 
margin-top:5px;
color:#789;
font-size:11px;
visibility: visible;
}

#signin_menu input[type=text], #signin_menu input[type=password] {
display:block;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid #ACE;
font-size:13px;
margin:0 0 5px;
padding:5px;
width:203px;
z-index:11;
}
#signin_menu p {
margin:0;
}
#signin_menu a {
color:#6AC;
}
#signin_menu label {
font-weight:normal;
}
#signin_menu p.remember {
padding:10px 0;
text-align:right;
}
#signin_menu p.forgot, #signin_menu p.complete {
clear:both;
margin:5px 0;
}
#signin_menu p a {
color:#27B!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing the filter:

progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#555555', EndColorStr='#2a2a2a', GradientType=0)

will fix your issue, dont ask my why though :D

Comment: those filters are so buggy for IE, better to stay away